# uscxml (statecharts) and Python

Tags: python, statechart

Are there any examples of `uscxml` (statechart) code using the Python bindings?

E.g. I'm having the following problem. Running `uscxml-browser -v <scxml-chart-file>` works (showing me it's going through the transitions) but how do I run this as Python code.